# Running assembly in AppDomain using specific permissions

Tags: c#, appdomain

I need to start my console application in a separate `AppDomain` under the `Network Service` account.

I create the app domain lie this:

```
d = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyDomain");
```

and than I ran my application

```
d.ExecuteAssembly("MyAssembly.exe");
```

Which method do I need to use for setting `Network Service` permissions on the app domain?

Answer (score 0):

AppDomain helps you to create a specific SandBox. All the details available from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763046.aspx

On the other hand, if you specifically need "NetworkService" account, using a service may help you as explained from http://stuartpreston.net/blog/2010/05/18/running-and-debugging-a-net-application-as-network-service-in-visual-studio-2010/